# Lighthouse audit & GtMetrix analysis both fail

Tags: debugging, gtmetrix

I am trying to audit my website in order to evaluate performance however I get on both testing platforms errors connected to javascript.
More specificaly using chrome dev tools debugger stops immediately after load showing VM1208:
(function anonymous(
) {
debugger
})

If I run lighthouse on web I get NO FPC error.
GTMetrix gives Debugger in page JavaScript pausing JavaScript execution